# receiving Cannot GET / error in react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I was trying to make own chatgpt version so i found this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwM23_kF4v4&t=2377s  After creating front end this guy added this

```
const app = express()
const port = 3080

app.post('/',async (req,res)=>{
    const response = await openai.createCompletion({
        model: "text-davinci-003",
        prompt: "Say this is a test",
        max_tokens: 7,
        temperature: 0,
      });
      console.log(response.data.choices[0].text);
      res.json({
        data: response.data
      })
})

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
})
```

I think the problem occurs in that part, but can't find it by myself bcs i actually don't know react and node.js.

tried switching port value to 3000 and adding babel to webpack

Comment: Your express app is listening for [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) requests but you're sending a [GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET).

Comment: could you tell me how to change my code to start it working?

Comment: Change `app.post` to `app.get`

Comment: i receive blackscreen with this message
{"data":{"id":"cmpl-6etVEpLVoVV4JNvji79Icla6RZXV0","object":"text_completion","created":1675204492,"model":"text-davinci-003","choices":[{"text":"\n\nThis is indeed a test","index":0,"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":"length"}],"usage":{"prompt_tokens":5,"completion_tokens":7,"total_tokens":12}}}

Comment: Then it's working. Congrats.

Comment: the problem is that my front-end doesn't load, all was okay, till i added all this stuff.And i can't understand why it prevents my page from full load

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you. We don't know what your front end is trying to do, or how it's built, or what the error is, assuming there is one. You can't just say "it doesn't work" and expect answers. Read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).